# Border around radio buttons styled as toggle buttons

Tags: wpf

I have some radio buttons styled as toggel buttons:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="B1" Width="65" IsChecked="{Binding Path=B1Checked}"/>
  <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="B2" Width="65" IsChecked="{Binding Path=B2Checked}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I am trying to add a yellow border around the button so that when the button is checked, a border is displayed, otherwise no border is displayed.

I was able to add `<Border>` elements around each button and have them display properly but after I added the borders, the buttons no longer were in the same group so checking one no longer automatically unchecked the other.

Is there a simple style I can apply that would give me the borders I am looking for?  I want the buttons to look as they do now just with the border when they are checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your `Radiobutton`s same `GroupName` `<RadioButton GroupName="myGroup"/>` they will come under same group and will behave the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  Totally forgot about GroupName.